# Piping a global input into a Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

Suppose I have the following Shiny module, which doesn't work as I intend:

```
library(shiny)

# module
module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("choose"))
}
module_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$choose <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "option", 
                label = "choose your option",
                choices = c("a", "b", input$entered_text))
  })
}
# ui and server
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("entered_text", label = "Enter a custom option:"),
  module_ui("xyz")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(module_server, "xyz")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I pipe the global input, `input$entered_text` (Line 10), into the module so that the text that the user entered shows up as a choice on the `selectInput` UI?

I think I am supposed to use `reactive()`, but I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you are supposed to use `reactive()` and pass the result of the `entered_text` to your module, as such:

```
library(shiny)

# module
module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("choose"))
}
module_server <- function(input, output, session, et) {
  output$choose <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "option", 
                label = "choose your option",
                choices = c("a", "b", et()))
  })
}
# ui and server
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("entered_text", label = "Enter a custom option:"),
  module_ui("xyz")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  et <- reactive(input$entered_text)
  callModule(module_server, "xyz", et)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wow, that was such a simple solution!  The key was to use the function format `et()` as an argument for `selectInput`  Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

`callModule()` was softly deprecated in Shiny 1.5.0 in favor of `moduleServer()`. Here is an updated version of @Bas's answer:

```
library(shiny)

# module
module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("choose"))
}
# ui and server
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("entered_text", label = "Enter a custom option:"),
  module_ui("xyz")
)
server <- function(input, output, session, et) {
  et <- reactive(input$entered_text)
  moduleServer(
    "xyz",
    function(input, output, session) {
    output$choose <- renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = "option", 
                  label = "choose your option",
                  choices = c("a", "b", et()))
    })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```